# Error compiling PHP-7.1.20 with MariaDB 10.3.9

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to compile php-7.1.20 on ubuntu 16.04 server.

I have also compiled Mariadb 10.3.9 at `/opt/mariadb`.

I am trying to compile php with the option `--with-mysqli=/opt/mariadb/bin/mysql_config`.

I have applied this patch

https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=75612&patch=mysql-mariadb-10.3.patch&revision=latest

After applying the patch I am getting this error:

> error: ‘zend_mysqli_globals {aka struct _zend_mysqli_globals}’ has no member named ‘reconnect’

Comment: This https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/176 might help (unless you have read it aleady).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Nic3500 but I belive that thread is for python-mariadb.I am looking for a solution for php-mariadb

Answer (score 3):

This needs to be fixed in PHP:

While both MySQL and MariaDB documentation clearly states that the `MYSQL` structure should be considered as opaque, PHP accesses internal member `reconnect` of the `MYSQL` structure, instead of using `mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &value)`.

Mea culpa: It was likely me which wrote that code 15 years ago, since the option `MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT` didn't exist. It was also me, which added the reconnect option to mysql->options.reconnect when I wrote MariaDB Connector/C from scratch.

Comment: Great to have your comment